# How to run suspended guest ( Windows 2003 32bit) on a Windows XP host using VMWare Workstation 8

Tags: virtual-machine

I am trying to run a suspended guest ( Windows 2003 32bit) on a windows xp host using VMWare Workstation 8 and I get the message "The virtual machine you are attempting to restore is using the NX/ED CPU feature, but your host does not support it."Now someone recommended to power on vm ware workstation 8 on a more 'primitive cpu'. But how do I do this when I have only one PC?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the solution offered in the [VMWare KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006111).

It states:

```
To resolve this issue, you must remove the suspend state from the virtual machine. 

To remove the suspend state from the virtual machine:

 1. Close VMware Workstation.
 2. Locate the virtual machine's folder.
 3. Delete the .VMSS and .LCK, files.
```

It does warn that removing the suspend state is the same as rebooting a PC.  You will lose any unsaved work.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I already know this article. Sadly the suspended state has to remain.

Comment: @WernerBalleis - If you don't have a different computer and you cannot "reboot" the virtual machine you don't have any options.  You are attempting to use a virtual machine on a computer that doesn't support NX/ED which means it cannot be restored.